# Linux: Curl installed but -bash: :curl: command not found

Tags: bash, debian, debian-stretch

Running Debian Stretch on an r710.  Using the non-free/contrib build for driver support.

When I try to use packages that I've installed (curl, zpool, etc), I have to include the path to the package... Which is a pain when I don't always know where packages install to.

Two questions:

1. How do I remedy the path issue in the short term?
2. How do I amend Debian so that when packages are installed, their paths update/install automatically?

Comment: How are you installing them? What is the path to them?

Comment: Sudo apt-get install.  So in the case of curl: sudo apt-get install curl

Comment: What is the path to `curl` in this case that you have to specify? `/usr/bin/curl`? If so you've just messed up your `PATH` in your `.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: "which curl" gives me /usr/bin/curl.  I have not made modifications to paths or otherwise and I think the missing paths are an artifact of the Debian ISO I pulled down.  Which is why I'm trying to figure out how to get paths to install/work correctly moving forward.

Comment: What exactly is the command you're running that fails? Your error message says `-bash: :curl: command not found` but that would imply you're running `:curl` instead of `curl`

Comment: "curl (anything)" -> -bash: :curl: command not found

Comment: zpool status -> -bash zpool: command not found

Comment: This is still really weird. In the first case you have an extra colon. In the second case you're missing a colon. Please make sure to copy-paste the error exactly, [it matters a lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). What does `echo "$PATH"` say?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` are messed up; "I have to include the path to ..." says it all.

Comment: @MartinZeitler That's what I would have assumed as well, but apparently `which` is found without a path, and is in turn able to find `curl`.

Comment: @thatotherguy also `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d` could be at fault... or even `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: This is not reproducible. `curl` gets installed in `/usr/bin` which is on your `PATH` even in the most barren of environments. If it isn't, you have manually screwed up your configuration, badly.

Answer (score 0):

Just install it by:

apt install curl

or sudo apt install curl

Comment: Downvote. OP stated that it's already installed, that's not the issue.

Comment: In fact the specific package curl is already installed, so this answer is not an answer to the main question.

Answer (score -2):

#### Find where the command is stored by

```
which <command>
```

#### Either you can try run curl from the output above for example /usr/bin/curl then try execute this:

```
 /usr/bin/curl
```

#### For a temporary fix until you solve the real problem you can do:

```
cd /usr/local/bin; ln -s $(which curl) curl
```

#### Or you can just set an alias:

```
echo "alias curl='$(which curl)'" >> ~/.bashrc; . ~/.bashrc
```

## Troubleshoot your problem:

#### Check so PATH folder has the correct paths exported:

```
printf "%s\n" $PATH
```

#### Modify current PATH

Use the export command to add new paths and see if that works you can then update your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, but first you can try in shell without adding it permanent to $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/missed/bin/folder
```

### To format your PATH variable for easy viewing in future you can add below function to your .bashrc

```
function path(){
    old=$IFS
    IFS=:
    printf "%s\n" $PATH
    IFS=$old
 }
```

Comment: I have done: $ docker run -it --name flask_test ubuntu /bin/bash   Then: $ curl returns "bash: curl: command not found"  Then $ which curl       returns nothing.

Comment: @Alex75 I have same issue too. Do you have any solutions for this error?

Comment: @JerryChong, I think the current ubuntu:latest  don't have "curl" preinstalled.  
``apt-get update && apt-get install curl`` will install it.  
THEN  ``which curl`` will return "/usr/bin/curl".

Comment: Correct @Alex75, I use Gentoo and I just tried Ubuntu so thx for the heads up!

Comment: Bad answer. `which curl` returns nothing at all, even though curl is installed.

Comment: If `which` can find it, it's already on your `PATH`; so this is completely useless advice. [Don't use the nonstandard `which` anyway.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: @Alex75 You could try " docker exec -it ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'which curl'" if you want to use bash otherwise "docker exec -it ubuntu which curl" is enough. Both work over here and outptuts: /usr/bin/curl and your command is not correct, it should be 'docker exec -it flask_test /bin/bash -c 'which curl''